# Definition of connection 1-forms - when we write $A(X^\#)=X$, is $A(X^\#)$ meant to be constant?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Let $A$ be a connection $1$-form on a principal $G$-bundle and $X\in\mathfrak{g}$.

By the [definition of connection $1$-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)), $A(X^\#)=X$. However, $A(X^\#)\in C^\infty(P,\mathfrak{g})$, so the equation doesn't make sense. Is $A(X^\#)$ assumed to be constant? That is, $$A(X^\#)_p=X$$ for all $p\in P$?

Comment: Yes. It means that for any $p\in P$, your second expression is true.

Comment: @user17945 Thank you!